# how to check upgrades for third party dependencies in a Gradle libs.versions.toml

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

how to check   upgrades for  third party dependencies in a Gradle libs.versions.toml

Earlier when we opened the build.gradle file and checked for the problems section we could check if new version is available for the availabe updates, is there a way to check it directly in the `libs.versions.toml`  file.

Comment: I use this:  https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.ben-manes.versions and then run `./gradlew dependencyUpdates`.  Might not be a direct as looking in the IDE, but it prints to a file in the `build/` dir and you can go through them there.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.+, there is now a built in linter that highlights outdated libraries.

[image: libs.versions.toml]

Comment: Can you add more this than just the picture?  Where do you make the dependency declaration?  What is the library being used?  You have just a value for version number

Comment: This feature is not library dependent. To enable (or check if you have) this feature, go to `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inspections`. In the section `Android Lint: Correctness`, tick or enable the option: `Obsolete Gradle Dependency`. This option's description will explain how it works. PS: the varible name for version does not matter, ie: room-version vs room. This feature will evaluate the version number, and if its obsolete, it will be highlighted. The name/library does not matter as long as your implementation calls and toml syntax is correct. @JPM